# Echo State Network learning Mackey-Glass function, but how?

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics, network

I got this [example of a minimal Echo State Network](http://minds.jacobs-university.de/mantas/code) (ESN) which I analyse while trying to understand [Echo State Networks](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Echo_state_network). Unfortunately I have some problems understanding why this really works. It all breaks down to the questions:

- [ What defines | What is] the *echo state* of an ESN?
- What is it that makes an ESN so easy and fast learning of such complex nonlinear functions like the  Mackey-Glass function?

First here is a little piece of code that shows the important part of initialization:

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Generate the ESN reservoir
% 
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

rand('seed', 42);

trainLen = 2000;
testLen  = 2000;
initLen  = 100;
data     = load('MackeyGlass_t17.txt');

%         Input neurons
inSize  = 1; 
%         Output neurons 
outSize = 1;
%         Reservoir size
resSize = 1000;
%         Leaking rate
a       = 0.3; 
%         Input weights
Win     = ( rand(resSize, (inSize+1) ) - 0.5) .* 1;
%         Reservoir weights
W       = rand(resSize, resSize) - 0.5;
```

---

## Running the reservoir:

I understand that every single data-point of the input data set is propagated from the input neuron to the reservoir neurons. After a warm-up of size `initLen` the states are accepted and stored in matrix `X`. When this is done every single column of `X` represents a "*vector of reservoir neuron activations*". And here comes the point where I am not sure if I got it right:

The comment already says "*collected states*" or "*design matrix*" `X`. Am I getting this right, that all this does is storing the state of the whole network in the rows of matrix `X`?

- If we assume that `t` was just a time parameter then `X(:,t)` represents the network state of time `t` , isn't it?

In my examples this would mean that there are 1.900 time slices which represent the whole network state of their corresponding timeframe (`X` therefore is a `1002x1900` matrix). Another question that occurs to me here is

- why is a `1` (I guess it is the bias) and the input value `u` appended to this vector: `X(:,t-initLen) = [1;u;x];`

So:

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% Run the reservoir with the data and collect X.
% 
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%       Allocated memory for the design (collected states) matrix
X     = zeros((1+inSize) + resSize, trainLen - initLen);

%       Vector of reservoir neuron activations (used for calculation)
x     = zeros(resSize, 1);

%       Update of the reservoir neuron activations
xUpd  = zeros(resSize, 1);

for t = 1:trainLen
    
    u    = data(t);
    
    xUpd = tanh( Win * [1;u] + W * x );    
    x    = (1-a) * x + a * xUpd;
    
    if ( t > initLen )
        X(:,t-initLen) = [1;u;x];
    end
    
end
```

---

## Training part:

The training part is also a little *magic* to me yet. I am familiar how linear regression works, so this is not the problem here.

What I see is that this part just uses the hole state matrix `X` and performs a single linear regression step on the input data to generate the output weight vector `Wout` and that's it.

So all that's been done so far - if I'm not mistaken - is initializing the output weights according to the state matri `X` which itself was generated using input data and randomly gernerated (input and reservoir) weights.

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% Train the output
% 
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%       Set the corresponding target matrix directly
Yt    = data(initLen+2:trainLen+1)';

%       Regularization coefficient
reg   = 1e-8;  

%       Get X transposed - needed twice therefore it is a little faster
X_T   = X';

%       Yt * pseudo_inverse(X); (linear regression task)
Wout  = Yt * X_T * (X * X_T + reg * eye(1+inSize+resSize))^(-1);
```

---

## Running the ESN in a generative mode:

I can run this in two modes: generative or predictive. But well, this is the part where I just can say: "*Well, .. it works.*" not having the exact idea why it is.

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% Run the trained ESN in a generative mode. no need to initialize here, 
% because x is initialized with training data and we continue from there.
% 
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Y = zeros(outSize,testLen);
u = data(trainLen+1);

for t = 1:testLen 
    
    xUpd   = tanh( Win*[1;u] + W*x );
    x      = (1-a)*x + a*xUpd;
    
    %        Generative mode:
    u      = Wout*[1;u;x];

    %      This would be a predictive mode:
    %u      = data(trainLen+t+1);

    Y(:,t) = u;
    
end
```

It works pretty well as you can see (generative mode):

[image]

I know this is a quiet huge "*question*" if this can even be considered as one. I feel like I am understanding the single parts but what I'm missing is **the big picture** of this magic black box called Echo State Network.

Answer (score 0):

> [ What defines | What is] the echo state of an ESN?

The echo state property states that the spectral radius of the W matrix must be < 1, ensuring that a null input will drive the state to the zero vector.

> What is it that makes an ESN so easy and fast learning of such complex
>   nonlinear functions like the Mackey-Glass function?

It is because you just need to learn the output weights. The input and reservoir weights are randomly initialized and never modified.

> If we assume that t was just a time parameter then X(:,t) represents the network state of time t, isn't it?

Yes. The X matrix is like a complete history of the reservoir activations (which are the states). You are transforming your input space into this new state space.

> Another question that occurs to me here is
>   why is a 1 (I guess it is the bias) and the input value u appended to this vector: X(:,t-initLen) = [1;u;x];

Because the network makes its predictions based not only on the current state, but also on the current input (and yes, the 1 is the bias). It is something like "if I'm on this situation (X) and do that (input), what happens (output)?"

> I'm missing is the big picture of this magic black box called Echo State Network.

An ESN basically transforms your input non-linearly into a large state space. Since the reservoir is usually large, we expect it to extract interesting dynamics of your data even with random weights. The [ELM](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/) does the same for static tasks, which is also related to [Random Projections](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~markad/publications/hdwb-nips-2007.pdf). It is also related to the fact that higher dimensional problems tend to be easier to be solved by linear methods (see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24147/why-linear-transformation-can-improve-classification-accuracy-when-the-dimension) and [here](http://www.quora.com/Support-Vector-Machines/How-does-going-to-higher-dimension-help-data-get-linearly-separable-which-was-non-linearly-separable-in-actual-dimension)). The echo state is required on top of that to ensure stability of the system.